# How do I convert this pinescript v2 to pinescript v4?

Tags: pine-script

I have a pinescript v2 that needs to be converted to v4 to be able to use alert messages, but I still haven't understood how, any inputs will be useful, thanks. This script was developed a long time back and visiting it now is confusing me. I have been reading that the variables need to be declared first, I get that, but what is the most efficient way to convert this into v4 of pine?

```
//@version=2
strategy("Bollinger + RSI, Double Strategy (by ChartArt) v1.1", shorttitle="CA_-_RSI_Bol_Strat_1.1", overlay=true)


///////////// RSI
RSIlength = input(6,title="RSI Period Length") 
RSIoverSold = 50
RSIoverBought = 50
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, RSIlength)


///////////// Bollinger Bands
BBlength = input(200, minval=1,title="Bollinger Period Length")
BBmult = 2 // input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50,title="Bollinger Bands Standard Deviation")
BBbasis = sma(price, BBlength)
BBdev = BBmult * stdev(price, BBlength)
BBupper = BBbasis + BBdev
BBlower = BBbasis - BBdev
source = close
buyEntry = crossover(source, BBlower)
sellEntry = crossunder(source, BBupper)
plot(BBbasis, color=aqua,title="Bollinger Bands SMA Basis Line")
p1 = plot(BBupper, color=silver,title="Bollinger Bands Upper Line")
p2 = plot(BBlower, color=silver,title="Bollinger Bands Lower Line")
fill(p1, p2)


///////////// Colors
switch1=input(true, title="Enable Bar Color?")
switch2=input(true, title="Enable Background Color?")
TrendColor = RSIoverBought and (price[1] > BBupper and price < BBupper) and BBbasis < BBbasis[1] ? red : RSIoverSold and (price[1] < BBlower and price > BBlower) and BBbasis > BBbasis[1] ? green : na
barcolor(switch1?TrendColor:na)
bgcolor(switch2?TrendColor:na,transp=50)


///////////// RSI + Bollinger Bands Strategy
if (not na(vrsi))

    if (crossover(vrsi, RSIoverSold) and crossover(source, BBlower))
        strategy.entry("RSI_BB_L", strategy.long, stop=BBlower, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="RSI_BB_L")
    else
        strategy.cancel(id="RSI_BB_L")
        
    if (crossunder(vrsi, RSIoverBought) and crossunder(source, BBupper))
        strategy.entry("RSI_BB_S", strategy.short, stop=BBupper, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="RSI_BB_S")
    else
        strategy.cancel(id="RSI_BB_S")

//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=red, linewidth=2, style=areabr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html#) to convert your script to v3 and then use the converter tool to convert it to v4 and above.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Bollinger + RSI, Double Strategy (by ChartArt) v1.1", shorttitle="CA_-_RSI_Bol_Strat_1.1", overlay=true)


///////////// RSI
RSIlength = input(6, title="RSI Period Length")
RSIoverSold = 50
RSIoverBought = 50
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, RSIlength)


///////////// Bollinger Bands
BBlength = input(200, minval=1, title="Bollinger Period Length")
BBmult = 2  // input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50,title="Bollinger Bands Standard Deviation")
BBbasis = sma(price, BBlength)
BBdev = BBmult * stdev(price, BBlength)
BBupper = BBbasis + BBdev
BBlower = BBbasis - BBdev
source = close
buyEntry = crossover(source, BBlower)
sellEntry = crossunder(source, BBupper)
plot(BBbasis, color=color.aqua, title="Bollinger Bands SMA Basis Line")
p1 = plot(BBupper, color=color.silver, title="Bollinger Bands Upper Line")
p2 = plot(BBlower, color=color.silver, title="Bollinger Bands Lower Line")
fill(p1, p2)


///////////// Colors
switch1 = input(true, title="Enable Bar Color?")
switch2 = input(true, title="Enable Background Color?")
TrendColor = RSIoverBought and price[1] > BBupper and price < BBupper and 
   BBbasis < BBbasis[1] ? color.red : 
   RSIoverSold and price[1] < BBlower and price > BBlower and BBbasis > BBbasis[1] ? 
   color.green : na
barcolor(switch1 ? TrendColor : na)
bgcolor(switch2 ? TrendColor : na, transp=50)


///////////// RSI + Bollinger Bands Strategy
if not na(vrsi)

    if crossover(vrsi, RSIoverSold) and crossover(source, BBlower)
        strategy.entry("RSI_BB_L", strategy.long, stop=BBlower, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="RSI_BB_L")
    else
        strategy.cancel(id="RSI_BB_L")

    if crossunder(vrsi, RSIoverBought) and crossunder(source, BBupper)
        strategy.entry("RSI_BB_S", strategy.short, stop=BBupper, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="RSI_BB_S")
    else
        strategy.cancel(id="RSI_BB_S")

//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=red, linewidth=2, style=areabr)
```